# What is Celery Application ( celery.app.App )?

Tags: python, celery

Can somebody please explain me what is celery Application object, noted [here](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/v2.2.4/reference/celery.app.html) and what purposes it should be used for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read this document:

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/internals/app-overview.html

The `App` is an instance of the Celery library, you can subclass app to override almost any part and corner of how Celery behaves.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of chord implementation via Celery App?